# Модули AMD не видят подключаемые плагины

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, amd, модули

Использую Gulp для сборки проекта и RequireJS для сборки AMD модулей. Вот из gulpfile.js (библиотеки собираются в libs.min.js):

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['common-js'], function () {
  return gulp.src([
   'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
   'app/libs/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
   'app/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js',
   'app/libs/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js',
   'app/libs/font-awesome/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome-all.min.js'
])
   .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts'));
});
```

Вот как подключены скрипты в html:

```
<!-- Какой-то код -->
<script src="scripts/libs.min.js"></script>
<script data-main="scripts/config_require.min.js" src="scripts/lib/require.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

В одном из модулей использую, например, какую-нибудь функцию Bootstrap:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
var modals = {};

modals.initModals = function() {
    $('#carouselExampleFade').carousel();
};

return modals;
});
```

В файле, где подключаются модули вызываю свою функцию:

```
define(['jquery', 'modals'], function ($, modals) {

/*Какой-то код*/

modals.initModals();
});
```

В итоге в консоли получаю ошибку:  "$(...).carousel is not a function". С другими библиотеками та же самая ошибка возникает. Значит ли это, что модули не видят библиотеки? Или дело в Gulp'e? Потому что если подключать все файлы отдельно, то ошибки не будет:

```
<script src="scripts/lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/test.js"></script>

//Test.js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#carouselExampleFade').carousel();
});
```

Comment: Если убрать карусель, то что будет?

Comment: Что значит "убрать"? Из DOM или убрать скрипт, активирующий ее? Очевидно, если убрать скрипт, то ошибки не будет. Скрипты, не использующие библиотеки (за исключением JQuery), работают нормально. Может быть потому, что jQuery указан в зависимостях к модулям